# Is it possible to circumvent European censorship?

Tags: ps3, psn, south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I've bought South Park: The Stick of Truth on the European PSN.

Unfortunately, some scenes (mainly the abortion and anal probe scenes) are censored:

[image: abortion and anal probe scenes censored messages]

I first thought it was a joke, as the censored messages are quite funny, but it's not.

Does someone know a way to get around this censorship? For example, can I download the game from the US store without buy it again?

I'm 29 years old, I think I'm old enough to perform an abortion on men if I want to.

Comment: Same here on 360, as far as I know the PS3 isn't region locked, but the 360 is. I'm open to correction on that, so you could order the US copy (confirm that though). Alternatively you could watch the censored bits on Youtube...? There's not much cut, but it's very annoying.

Comment: @fredley: Why did you **CENSOR** that text from the title, which would be highly useful to anyone googling for this exact question?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft [This has come up before](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/1749/3610). The question makes perfect sense without the offensive words in the title. I'm happy for references in the question body (which is indexed by Google), but titles are much more visible to people casually browsing the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

The PC version is the only one available in Europe that's not censored in all of it, but that would require buying it again as well as having a PC capable of running it. On PC, censorship only applies in Germany and Austria in Europe -- and then, apparently only in relation to the removal of Nazi-themed symbolism.

The US and EU PSN stores are entirely separate.

Comment: Austria used to not be that stupid on censorship :(

Comment: my guess would be that having two localised german versions, one with nazis and one without, would be too much trouble.

Comment: Too bad :/ I'll wait a little before accepting your answer, in case of someone has a magical solution. That's comfort me in the idea to not buy PS4/XONE but a gamer PC instead...

Comment: In some cases what you would have to do would be have an US IP address (vpn), credit card and account.

Comment: @TZHX This answer is not entirely correct. The scenes mentioned in the question are uncensored in the PC version in Germany and Austria as well. The console versions there have a 16+ rating and the PC version an 18+ rating for this reason. The only censorship in both versions are swastikas which are forbidden, because legally video games have not been accepted as an "art" form, like films, where they are mostly allowed. This led to a three week release delay, because Ubisoft forgot to delete the swastikas :D It doesn't have any harsh cuts like missing scenes, only missing symbols.

Comment: @Getz On a side note: It was the publisher's decision to censor the scenes, unlike what the ingame message implies. It would just have gotten a higher rating in some countries, like the PC version, and asked why they censored the game, they called it a "marketing decision". It did create quite a buzz, or maybe they just thought there are more young players on consoles.

Comment: @Getz Stick of truth can run on a decent laptop.  I was running it just fine on my Lenovo Thinkpad Edge (No dedicated graphics)