# What has been removed from the Austrian "low violence" version of South Park - Stick of Truth?

Tags: version-differences, south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I am considering buying South Park - Stick of Truth via Steam, but here in Austria only the "low violence" - (censored) - version is legally available.

From what I have researched on the net so far, they censored at least the swastikas, which would be ok for me. I was not able to clarify if anything else has been cut out? If more has been censored I will most likely not buy it. Can anyone tell me what was removed?

Comment: it seems logical that your country would have a website listing such details, but I wouldn't know personally.

Comment: I've heard rumors of alien anal probing scenes being censored out and replaced with (allegedly vivid) descriptions of the images removed.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173875/is-it-possible-to-circumvent-european-censorship

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a video of the 7 scenes that have been cut [here](http://uk.ign.com/videos/2014/03/04/7-banned-moments-in-south-park-the-stick-of-truth). It's for Europe so I'm not sure it also applies to Austria.

[image]
Image found in [this article](http://kotaku.com/south-park-the-stick-of-truth-is-censored-outside-of-a-1530528203).

According to [this article](http://www.polygon.com/2014/3/5/5474918/why-south-park-the-stick-of-truth-was-delayed-in-austria-and-germany) Germany and Austria probably share the same censorship.
The game includes swastikas, which is a "symbol of an unconstitutional organization" in these countries.

> South Park: The Stick of Truth has been delayed in Austria and Germany because developer Obsidian Entertainment's role-playing game includes swastikas, which is a "symbol of an unconstitutional organization," a representative from Ubisoft confirmed to Polygon today.

If you stumble upon a cut scene you'll see this kind of image :
[image]

Here is [the censored scenes compared to their image description](http://youtu.be/9dBPKjnEP9g).

Answer (score 2):

The game is censored both in Europe (Swastikas, Nazis etc.) and in Australia (Anal probing and abortion)

*“Seven scenes of about 20 seconds each are censored in the EMEA console versions of South Park: The Stick of Truth. The decision to cut this content from the game was made by Ubisoft EMEA.”*

http://a.pomf.se/eczoaa.JPG